# Wear - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException while deserializing DataMap

Tags: android, wear-os

When converting a DataMap containing a long and an Asset I get the following exception:

```
E/JavaBinder( 1634): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder( 1634): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
E/JavaBinder( 1634):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
E/JavaBinder( 1634):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
E/JavaBinder( 1634):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bm.a(Unknown Source)
E/JavaBinder( 1634):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bm.a(Unknown Source)
E/JavaBinder( 1634):    at com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap.fromByteArray(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    for (DataEvent dataEvent : dataEvents) {
        final DataItem dataItem = dataEvent.getDataItem();
        byte [] data = (dataItem.isDataValid() ? dataItem.getData() : new byte[]{});
        Log.d(TAG, "Received data updates on URI: " + dataItem.getUri() + " " + data.length + " bytes");
        if (!dataItem.isDataValid() || data.length == 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, " - got invalid data on: " + dataItem.getUri());
            continue;
        }
        final DataMap dataMap = DataMap.fromByteArray(data); // <-- exception :(
```

Is this a known issue? If I get the data item on the same URI, it works fine, so the data is definitely there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the DataEvent -> DataItem -> DataMap from:

```
final DataItem dataItem = dataEvent.getDataItem();
byte [] data = dataItem.getData();
final DataMap dataMap = DataMap.fromByteArray(data);  <-- throws exception
```

to:

```
final DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem).getDataMap();
final DataMap dataMap = DataMap.fromByteArray(data);  <-- works!
```

Closing question.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is probably in this line of code, you don't give a size to the byte array

```
byte [] data = (dataItem.isDataValid() ? dataItem.getData() : new byte[]{});
```

can you try replacing this line with

```
byte [] data = (dataItem.isDataValid() ? dataItem.getData() : new byte[0]);
```

Comment: `dataitem.isDataValid()` is actually `true` and `dataItem.getData()` returns a `byte[]` of length 44. I changed to new byte[0] too for good measure.

Comment: does it still cause the exception ?